# Managing multiple appSettings in web.config ASP.NET Framework

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, app-config

I have one codebase, but there are 2 different instances of the app running on 2 different servers. Since I have only one web.config file, I would like to extend the `<appSettings>` section, which can include 2 different settings for those 2 projects.

Current `web.config` file `appSettings` section

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="AuditLogLocation" value="E:\\LOG\\Auditlogs" />
    <add key="DateFormat" value="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" />
    <add key="DefaultConnection" value="Data Source=*****.test.com;Initial Catalog=AppName;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
  </appSettings>
```

How can I extend the above section so that I can include a single appSettings file.

```
<appSettings configSource="appSettings.config"/>
```

and `appSettings.config` could contain the common keys and individual keys for those 2 projects.

Something like

```
{
  "AuditLogLocation": "E:\\LOG\\Auditlogs",
  "DateFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
  "Project1Settings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=*****.test.com;Initial Catalog=Project1;Integrated Security=SSPI",
    "apiSource" : "https://www.api-project1.com"
  },
  "Project2Settings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=*****.test.com;Initial Catalog=Project2;Integrated Security=SSPI",
    "apiSource" : "https://www.api-project2.com"
  }
}
```

Currently, I am using those appSettings values like

```
BaseDAL.ConfigureConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultConnection"]);
```

But I would like to change that to the new format and have the `DefaultConnection` value fetched based on the project (Project1Settings or Project2Settings)

Comment: Use [web.config transformations](https://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/working-with-multiple-web-config-files/4100)

Comment: There are only a few keys, I would like to have different for each project. I think it is easier to maintain the keys in a setting file rather replicating the whole web.config file. Don't you think so? I am more specifically wondering how to call another file in web-config `appSettings` section and use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultConnection"] for either Project 1 or 2

Comment: I assume you did not read the article